# Providing sharepoint groups as choice in the new item form

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, column, groups

I want to create a field in the new Item form where in it should display names of 4 sharepoint groups (with users) as choices to the user, where in the user can multi-select one or more choice of groups from the form to send  E-mail to all the members in the selected groups.

So my question is what type of a column should i select to get the above groups as options in the item form and how to create a workflow based on it which will trigger an Email to all the members in such groups.

Answer (score 0):

Make a field choise and add these groups. Then in Sharepoint designer, you need to have as many ifs as the choises:

[image: Sp designer if]